# MySql Select Query. >3 minutes response for 4M rows

Tags: mysql, performance

Agree there are a few mathematical calculations in the select query but surely not something which should affect the performance in such a way.

Below is the select query.

```
SELECT `p`.`id` as post_id, `p`.`description` as description, `p`.`rent` as rent, 
`p`.`created_at` as created_at, `p`.`title` as title, 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.created_at) as timestamp,
`p`.`user_id` as post_user_id, `p`.`bathrooms`, `p`.`bedrooms`, `p`.`created_at`, 
`p`.`address`, `p`.`lat`, `p`.`lng`, `p`.`posted_by`, `p`.`amenities`, `p`.`user_id`, 
`p`.`smoking_policy`, `p`.`sqft`, `p`.`dogs`, `p`.`cats`, `p`.`dwelling_type`,
`p`.`deposit`, 
`p`.`furnished`, `p`.`sublease`, `p`.`sublease_duration`, `p`.`lease`,          
`p`.`property_type`,`p`.`source`, `p`.`images_json`, `sub`.`name` as sub_category_name,   
`sub`.`id` as sub_category_id, `sub`.`text` as sub_category_text, `p`.`lat` as lat, 
`p`.`lng` as lng, `p`.`phone` as phone, 
(3959 * acos( cos( radians(42.3584308) ) * cos( radians( p.lat ) ) * cos( radians(  
 p.lng ) - radians(-71.0597732) ) + sin( radians(42.3584308) ) * sin( radians( p.lat ) 
) ) ) AS distance
FROM (`T1` p)
JOIN `sub_categories` as sub ON `sub`.`id` = `p`.`sub_category_id`
AND `p`.`lng` between (-71.0597732 - 20/abs(cos(radians(42.3584308 ))*69)) 
and (-71.0597732 + 20/abs(cos(radians(42.3584308))*69)) 
AND `p`.`lat` between 42.3584308 - (20/69) and 42.3584308 + (20/69)
AND `rent` <= '9200'
AND `rent` >= '7000'
AND `bedrooms` <= '4'
AND `bathrooms` <= '3'
AND `dogs` =  '1'
AND `p`.`sub_category_id` =  '2'
HAVING `distance` <= '100'
ORDER BY `p`.`created_at` desc
LIMIT 0,12;
```

The search should provide available listings within a periphery of input address (lat, long coordinates).

AND condition parameters (rent, bedrooms etc…) and associated values are dynamically assigned based on front end selection.

Table structure is herewith.

```
CREATE TABLE `T1` (
`id` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',`user_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`sub_category_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`description` text,`title` text,
`rent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`utilities` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`bathrooms` float DEFAULT NULL,
`bedrooms` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`address` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`lat` double DEFAULT NULL,`lng` doubleDEFAULT NULL,
`dwelling_type` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
`furnished` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`lease_transfer_fees` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`dogs` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`cats` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`parking_spots` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`smoking_policy` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
`deposit` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`sqft` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`posted_by` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`amenities` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
`sublease` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`sublease_duration` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`lease` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`external_id` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
`source` varchar(10) DEFAULT 'np',
`anchor` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
`property_type` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
`deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
`images_json` text,
`phone` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `user_id_index` (`user_id`),
KEY `filter_combined_index` (`created_at`,`lat`,`lng`,`sub_category_id`,`rent`,     
`bedrooms`,`bathrooms`,`sqft`,`dogs`,`cats`),
KEY `sub_category_id` (`sub_category_id`),
FULLTEXT KEY `text_search_index`    
(`title`,`description`,`smoking_policy`,`posted_by`,`dwelling_type`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The explain statement result is below.

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key             key_len    ref     rows      Extra
1   SIMPLE      sub     const   PRIMARY,id      PRIMARY         8          const    1      Using filesort
1   SIMPLE      p       ref     sub_category_id sub_category_id 8          const    188122  Using where
```

Is the table structure not efficient or the select query or mixture of both?

Surely 4m rows should not be a limiting factor. Thanks in advance for advice of resident experts.

TA!

Comment: Depending on your other conditions, a lot of the rows may need to be scanned, since your calculations make it impossible to use an index for the rows you need to do the calculations on.

Comment: Can you calculate that distance and put it in a separate field? And if you can, index by that field

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Checking the query further, the query responds better without some columns added like Bedrooms, bathrooms. I am contemplating on having indexes on such columns.

Comment: @LHristov: Can't, the distances are decided by users from front end - it's a transitory value.

Answer (score 0):

You basically calculate the distance for every row that exists on the table:

```
SELECT [...]
(3959 * acos( cos( radians(42.3584308) ) * cos( radians( p.lat ) ) *
cos( radians(    p.lng ) - radians(-71.0597732) ) + sin(
radians(42.3584308) ) * sin( radians( p.lat )  ) ) ) AS distance
[...]
HAVING `distance` <= '100'
```

That forces MySQL to read the complete table on every query.

Additionally, the only index that includes coordinates is not usable for searches because it starts with `created_at`:

```
KEY `filter_combined_index` (`created_at`,`lat`,`lng`,`sub_category_id`,`rent`,
`bedrooms`,`bathrooms`,`sqft`,`dogs`,`cats`),
```

You can try a simple per-coordinate search, with an appropriate index:

```
WHERE lat BETWEEN :lat_from AND :lat_to
and lng BETWEEN :lng_from AND :lng_to
```

... where those from and two values belong to the bounding square. Once you've identified only the potential matches, you can fine-tune the results with an actual circle.

Comment: Thanks! I have changed the index and can start seeing some improvement in the performance. Will have to apply theory of deduction to see which index combination works best.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the database to do a lot of work here, but I'd also suggest restructuring your query slightly?

Firstly, you're using a join, but you're not explicitly using a `WHERE` clause, so you're actually specifying a very big `JOIN` condition. Internally there's a good chance MySql will automatically figure out that it's actually just a `WHERE` clause, but given that none of the rows in that join seem to have any bearing on the join itself, they should probably be in their own `WHERE`. This might make a big difference as it will theoretically reduce the number of rows before doing the join.

Secondly, you're using a `HAVING` clause, yet you don't have any aggregation in the query. General rule of thumb is that the `HAVING` clause is used for aggregation (eg COUNT or AVG), and the `WHERE` clause is used everywhere else.

As @Joachim and @LHristov have both touched on, doing those calculations at query time might not be such a great idea. You're already asking for a lot of data, but you're now asking it do run the calculation for every row it finds, and then run a separate calculation for the join. Unfortunately you've said you can't persist this so that can't be solved, but @Álvaro's suggesting might improve things if the following changes don't

Restructure the query to use `WHERE` instead of the `JOIN` and remove the having. I'd expect a resulting query to look like the following

```
SELECT 
  `p`.`id` as post_id, 
, `p`.`description` as description, 
, `p`.`rent` as rent
, `p`.`created_at` as created_at
, `p`.`title` as title
, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.created_at) as timestamp
, `p`.`user_id` as post_user_id
, `p`.`bathrooms`
, `p`.`bedrooms`
, `p`.`created_at`
, `p`.`address`
, `p`.`lat`
, `p`.`lng`
, `p`.`posted_by`
, `p`.`amenities`
, `p`.`user_id`,
, `p`.`smoking_policy`
, `p`.`sqft`
, `p`.`dogs`
, `p`.`cats`
, `p`.`dwelling_type`
, `p`.`deposit`
, `p`.`furnished`
, `p`.`sublease`
, `p`.`sublease_duration`
, `p`.`lease`
, `p`.`property_type`
, `p`.`source`
, `p`.`images_json`
, `sub`.`name` as sub_category_name
, `sub`.`id` as sub_category_id
, `sub`.`text` as sub_category_text
, `p`.`lat` as lat
, `p`.`lng` as lng
, `p`.`phone` as phone,
, (3959 * acos( cos( radians(42.3584308) ) * cos( radians( p.lat ) ) * cos( radians(
```

p.lng ) - radians(-71.0597732) ) + sin( radians(42.3584308) ) * sin( radians( p.lat ) 
) ) ) AS distance
    FROM (`T1` p)
    JOIN `sub_categories` as sub ON `sub`.`id` = `p`.`sub_category_id` AND `p`.`sub_category_id` =  '2'
    WHERE (`p`.`lng` BETWEEN (-71.0597732 - 20/abs(cos(radians(42.3584308 ))*69)) AND (-71.0597732 + 20/abs(cos(radians(42.3584308))*69)) )
    AND (`p`.`lat` BETWEEN (42.3584308 - (20/69)) and (42.3584308 + (20/69)) )
    AND `rent` <= 9200
    AND `rent` >= 7000
    AND `bedrooms` <= 4
    AND `bathrooms` <= 3
    AND `dogs` =  1
    AND `distance` <= 100
    ORDER BY `p`.`created_at` desc
    LIMIT 0,12;

Hopefully as mentioned before, this will cause the number of rows that the calculation is performed on to be reduced considerably before doing any calculation and `JOIN`, whereas just having the `JOIN` may be causing it to return all rows with calculation before checking if they join. MUCH slower as you can imagine

I also just noticed that you're selecting a few of the columns multiple times such as `created_at` and `user_id`? Not sure if intentional or not but can make a minor difference.

Also, the where clause conditions for fields such as `bedrooms`, `rent`, `dogs` etc that are integers, are all being compared as if they're strings? I've changed that in the query above.

Comment: You have created_at twice - well 3 times really

Comment: I know - Mentioned that in the answer, as the original query has them duplicated. Wasn't sure if it was intentional or not so I left it but made reference to it

Comment: Agree on the redundant column fetches - taken them out. Interesting comment regarding having clause - surprisingly mysql is throwing syntax error if i use and clause instead of having for the 'distance <=' check. Coming back with error as 'undefined column distance'.

Comment: Ah yeah my bad. The `where` clause only works on named fields, or you have to put the calculation in the `where` clause as well so it can recalculate it which I don't recommend. Alternatively you can put it all in a sub-query and put the `where` clause on that which might work well

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment, taking advantage of the answer window formatting options.

FWIW, I find this easier to read... and I'd bind distance as a function...

```
SELECT p.id post_id
     , p.description 
     , p.rent 
     , p.title
     , p.user_id post_user_id
     , p.bathrooms
     , p.bedrooms
     , p.created_at
     , p.address
     , p.posted_by
     , p.amenities
     , p.smoking_policy
     , p.sqft
     , p.dogs
     , p.cats
     , p.dwelling_type
     , p.deposit
     , p.furnished
     , p.sublease
     , p.sublease_duration
     , p.lease
     , p.property_type
     , p.source
     , p.images_json
     , sub.name sub_category_name
     , sub.id sub_category_id
     , sub.text sub_category_text
     , p.lat 
     , p.lng 
     , p.phone 
     , my_distance_function(p.lat,p.lng,71.0597732,42.3584308) distance
  FROM T1 p
  JOIN sub_categories sub
    ON sub.id = p.sub_category_id     
 WHERE my_distance_function(p.lat,p.lng,71.0597732,42.3584308) <= 100
   AND p.lng BETWEEN -71.452028 AND -70.6675175
   AND p.lat BETWEEN 42.0685757 AND 42.6482859
   AND rent <= 9200     
   AND rent >= 7000
   AND bedrooms <= 4
   AND bathrooms <= 3
   AND dogs =  1
   AND p.sub_category_id = 2

 ORDER 
    BY p.created_at DESC
 LIMIT 0,12;
```